# Parsing or decode this string to array or json

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

Does someone know how to parse this string bellow like an array or in json, there are for lines, i want to group the results for each line when this } close

the string:

```
string(544) "a:4:{s:18:"_1514316350293_293";a:4:{s:14:"customer_group";s:1:"3";s:9:"condition";s:1:"2";s:5:"somme";s:6:"500.00";s:5:"price";s:4:"0.00";}s:18:"_1514316394524_524";a:4:{s:14:"customer_group";s:1:"2";s:9:"condition";s:1:"2";s:5:"somme";s:6:"500.00";s:5:"price";s:4:"0.00";}s:18:"_1514316395828_828";a:4:{s:14:"customer_group";s:1:"3";s:9:"condition";s:1:"1";s:5:"somme";s:6:"500.00";s:5:"price";s:5:"29.40";}s:18:"_1514316396756_756";a:4:{s:14:"customer_group";s:1:"2";s:9:"condition";s:1:"1";s:5:"somme";s:6:"500.00";s:5:"price";s:5:"29.40";}}"
```

the first line is :

```
"customer_group"=>"3", "condition"=>"2", "somme"=>"500.00", "price"=>"0.00"
```

Comment: Use [unserialize](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: Yes, it works thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the @Valdeir Psr answer, i have to use the `unserialize()` function